# Do Boron and Silicon form metallic-type bonds in alloys?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, glass

For context I am a physics student currently doing a project that involves metallic glasses. I am trying to figure out if you can get Ionic bonds inside an alloy with metalloids. More specifically, I have 2 examples.

- Iron,Nickel,Boron
- Palladium, Copper, Silicon

I have recently found out about Arkel–Ketelaar triangles and assume they answer my question but I'm not entirely sure how to use them in the context of an alloy of three components. I am also not sure if I need to use a particular measure of electronegativity or if any will do.

Comment: "When in Rome, do as the Romans do." In a predominantly metallic environment, B and Si would act somewhat like metals.

Comment: @IvanNeretin This was my suspicion, but can you maybe link me to a source for this? Its ok if it's a book or something I can get from my library.

Comment: Silicon makes many binary metallic compounds (silicides) with most metals in the periodic table (Al, Ag, and Au being outliers). There are three Si-B alloys, SiB$_{3}$, SiB$_{6}$, and SiB$_{n}$ (it has some width to the phase field, and $n$ is about 23.39 at the peritectic point).

Comment: The two examples are been used to make metallic glasses. Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_metal#:~:text=The%20best%20glass%2Dforming%20alloys,called%20the%20%22confusion%22%20effect.).

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I know they've been used to make Metallic Glasses, what I'm curious about is if the bonds between those atoms and the rest are of a metallic sort.